# Correlation using scipy

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, pearson-correlation

I have two variables, one called `polarity` and another called `sentiment`. I would like to see if exists a correlation between these two variables.
`polarity` can take values from `0` to `1` (continuous); `sentiment` can take values `-1, 0` and `1`.
I have tried as follows:

```
from scipy import stats

pearson_coef, p_value = stats.pearsonr(df['polarity'], df['sentiment']) 
print(pearson_coef)
```

but I have got the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Example of values:

```
polarity      sentiment
 
0.34            -1
0.12            -1
0.85             1
0.76             1
0.5              0
0.21             0
```

Comment: Not reproductible with the test data. Fix the `dtype` of your two columns, one is not numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you are dealing with a `dataframe`, you can do the following to learn the `dtypes` of the columns:

```
>>> df.info() 

 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   polarity   6 non-null      float64
 1   sentiment  6 non-null      object 

>>> df['sentiment'] = df.sentiment.map(float) # or do : df = df.astype(float)

>>> df.info()

 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   polarity   6 non-null      float64
 1   sentiment  6 non-null      float64


>>> pearson_coef, p_value = stats.pearsonr(df['polarity'], df['sentiment']) 
>>> print(pearson_coef)
0.870679269711991

# Moreover, you can use pandas to estimate 'pearsonr' correlation matrix if you want to:
>>> df.corr()

           polarity  sentiment
polarity   1.000000   0.870679
sentiment  0.870679   1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

try as suggested in the comments to change all your dataframe columns to numeric dtypes:

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

before calling the pearsonr function.